# How to search for a particular message in JMS queue

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am sending some messages to a JMS queue. What are the possible ways to search for a particular message in a queue to consume?

I tried out in the following way: I am setting the `JMSCorrelationID` while sending a message to the queue:

```
 public void createDQueue(String queuename, String json, Integer userid) {
          try {

                QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );
                Queue queue = session.createQueue(queuename);
                ObjectMessage objectMessage = session.createObjectMessage();
                objectMessage.setJMSCorrelationID(String.valueOf(userid));
                objectMessage.setObject(json);
                session.createSender(queue).send(objectMessage);
                session.close();
                connection.close();
          }catch(Exception e){
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
```

In the consumer code I want to get that particular message based on the `JMSCorrelationID`. I am not able to get that particular message. Can you suggest a solution?

```
public void getSpecificMessage(String queuename, Integer userid) {

         try {
            QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory( "tcp://localhost:61616");
                ((ActiveMQConnectionFactory) connectionFactory).setUseAsyncSend(true);
                QueueConnection connection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
                connection.start();
                QueueSession session = connection.createQueueSession( false,
                     QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE );
                String id = String.valueOf(userid);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(queuename);
            QueueReceiver receiver = session.createReceiver(queue, "JMSCorrelationID="+id);
             Message message = receiver.receive();              
        } catch (JMSException e) {              
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

Comment: I think you made a mistake when posting your code... The first code block is not correct. You can click the `edit` link underneath your question to correct that in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your first problem is that you are trying to think about the message broker as a database, you must always remember this sage piece of advice, "A message broker is not a database".

There are certain limits on how deep a consumer or Queue browser can go into a destination before the broker will not page in more messages from disk, so you need to check your depth and see if its large than you maxPageSize setting and adjust as needed, but remember that messages paged in remain in memory until consumed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Tim Bish, as of now my queue has 10 messages for testing and I have to get specific message.I will surely adjust my maxPageSize later. Now I am using, String id = String.valueOf(tid); .setStringProperty("abc", id); (Producer).  when consuming I am getting problem here 'session.createConsumer(queue, "abc ="+id)'. If I directly pass the tid value, as  session.createConsumer(queue, "abc ='11'") I am able to consume. So, how should I pass my id value? Please tell me right way of passing id.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the id value in single quotes

```
"JMSCorrelationID='"+id+"'"
```

This functionality is not recommended to be used , there are lot more complications as explained by Tim , but if you want to obsolutely work with it make the change

Answer (score 1):

You can search messages using the `MeessageID` of a message. This would be fast as messaging providers index messages on message id. There are other way to search based on `CorrelationId`, meta data etc.

But please remember the primary objective of using a messaging provider is to connect applications in a time independent manner. The receiving application must get messages as soon as possible. If messages are piling up in a queue, it indicates a problem that must be addressed.

Comment: in my case, there are different users who send messages to queue, So I need to identify to whom(user) the message id belongs to. Then I think I need to maintain a key value pair indicating userid and respective messageid and search from there. Please tell me, is that the right way of doing? or any other alternative to get specific message and also see my comment to Tim Bish .

Comment: Not sure about your business logic. But I do not believe you need to search for messages. I would prefer to receive messages without any selector and then apply business logic on the received message.